# Is it possible to use Route attribute only to provide valid ASP.NET Controller route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I created a sample asp.net mvc5 webapi application and have a problem with routing.
I have a DummyController which I decoreted with [Route("dummyset")] attribute and I thought it is enough to register it.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("dummyset")]
    public IHttpActionResult DummySet([FromBody] DummyModel data)
    {
    }
```

However, it does not work. After adding this piece of code:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DummySET",
        routeTemplate: "api/dummy/dummyset",
        defaults: new { Controller = "Dummy", action = "DummySet", method = "POST" }
        );
```

in WebApiConfig.cs, everything works well.

Do I have to register it in these two places really? Is there any easier way to achive that? It may be a nightmare to maintain this later when number of endpoints increase to houndreds.

Comment: Have you added `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in your `RouteConfig.cs`?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Web API, to determine which action to invoke, the framework uses a routing table.

This one here is called [Convention-based routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) and it is required.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DummySET",
        routeTemplate: "api/dummy/dummyset",
        defaults: new { Controller = "Dummy", action = "DummySet", method = "POST" }
        );
```

And this one is called [Attribute Routing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("dummyset")]
 public IHttpActionResult DummySet([FromBody] DummyModel data)
 {
 }
```

If you change the above lines to the below snippet and remove attribute routing, it should work.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DummySET",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable it in route table like this

```
public class RouteConfig {

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {            
        //enable attribute routing
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        // After enabling routing following lines shouldn't be needed.
        // convention-based routes
        // routes.MapRoute(
        //     name: "DummySET",
        //     routeTemplate: "api/dummy/dummyset",
        //     defaults: new { Controller = "Dummy", action = "DummySet", method = "POST" }
        // );

        //default routes
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
    }
}
```